# Plot 3D in R: Classical spectral gasoline in function of octane

Tags: r, plot, lattice, rgl, pls

Load a data set comprising spectral intensities of 60 samples of gasoline at 401 wavelengths, and their octane ratings in pls package. In my example:

```
library(pls)

#Data set

data(gasoline)

'data.frame':   60 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ octane: num  85.3 85.2 88.5 83.4 87.9 ...
 $ NIR   : 'AsIs' num [1:60, 1:401] -0.0502 -0.0442 -0.0469 -0.0467 -0.0509 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr  "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. ..$ : chr  "900 nm" "902 nm" "904 nm" "906 nm"
```

I've like to plot the 3D representation of NIR in function of octane, my holy grail plot is:

[image: https://it.mathworks.com/help/stats/examples/partial-least-squares-regression-and-principal-components-regression.html]

But this output plot was create in matlab and not in R. The original code is (https://it.mathworks.com/help/stats/examples/partial-least-squares-regression-and-principal-components-regression.html):

```
load spectra
whos NIR octane

[dummy,h] = sort(octane);
oldorder = get(gcf,'DefaultAxesColorOrder');
set(gcf,'DefaultAxesColorOrder',jet(60));
plot3(repmat(1:401,60,1)',repmat(octane(h),1,401)',NIR(h,:)');
set(gcf,'DefaultAxesColorOrder',oldorder);
xlabel('Wavelength Index'); ylabel('Octane'); axis('tight');
grid on
```

Please any ideas or similar function/packages in R?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can do a plot like that in `rgl` or `plot3D`.  If you don't see how, please post some data and we'll show you.

Comment: I try below, but not so good presentation like MATLAB:
`library(rgl)`
`library(pls)`
`data(gasoline)`
`str(gasoline)`
`gasoline$ID<-seq(1:length(gasoline[,1]))`

  `open3d()`
  `x <- gasoline$octane`
  `y <- gasoline$NIR`
  `z <- gasoline$D`
  `plot3d(x, y, z, , type = "l", col = rainbow(1000))`

Comment: this could also be done in base graphics by using `persp()` to draw an empty plot, *saving the returned object*, and using the `$trans3d()` function it contains to add the lines (see the `Value:` section in `?persp`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives something like the Matlab plot:

```
library(rgl) 
library(pls) 
data(gasoline) 
str(gasoline) 
gasoline$ID <- seq(1:length(gasoline[,1])) 
open3d() 
x <- gasoline$octane 
y <- gasoline$NIR 
z <- gasoline$ID 
plot3d(x, 1:ncol(y), y, type = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "", zlab = "")
cols <- rainbow(1000)[(x - min(x))/(max(x) - min(x))*999 + 1]
for (i in seq_along(x))
  lines3d(x[i], 1:ncol(y), y[i,], col = cols[i])
```

[image: screenshot]

There are several differences:

- The handedness of the coordinate system.  (Octane increases towards the viewer in the rgl plot.)  You can change it in `rgl` using `par3d("userMatrix" = par3d("userMatrix") %*% diag(c(-1, 1,1,1)))` if you really want the Matlab style.
- I didn't draw axis labels.  The default ones in `rgl` are kind of ugly, and I
  was too lazy to use `mtext3d` to draw nicer ones.
- I didn't bother with background grids.  I don't like them, but if you really want them, you can get them with `grid3d`.
- Matlab doesn't show perspective.  If that's what you want, use `par3d(FOV = 0)`.
- The aspect ratios are different.  I think Matlab is using something like `aspect3d(1, 1, 0.75)`.
- The colors.  `rgl` uses the R color system, so if you can find a palette you
  like better than `rainbow(1000)`, use that.
- The price.